# Можно ли при создании Python-приложения использовать HTML и CSS?

Tags: python, html, css, веб-программирование, app

Можно ли при создании Python-приложения использовать HTML и CSS? Я знаю библиотеку EEL, но она ещё "сыровата". Раньше использовал React Native, но хотелось бы функционал создавать не на JavaScript, а на Python. Такое возможно? Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что правильно понял вопрос, но думаю если вы про десктоп, то вам нужно это: https://github.com/fyears/electron-python-example

Если про телефон: https://habr.com/ru/post/149898/